# What is preferable Entity Framework or Repository with Asp.Net Web Api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, repository

Hello I am new to Web Api and I have to create from the scratch as well.

I have worked with Web Api by calling and passing the data only now I have to create by my own so the problems I have faced I don't want to make it again in my application.

***Problem:***

The Web Api I have worked has repository implemented and using that repository object I have to contact with the database just like below example.

I have one DAL method DataRepository which has following methods which I have used to contact with the database:

```
GetAllAsync(ApplicationDbContext context, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
GetListAsync(ApplicationDbContext context, 
        Func<T, bool> where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
FirstOrDefaultAsync(ApplicationDbContext context, 
        Func<T, bool> where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
AddAsync(ApplicationDbContext context, params T[] items)
RemoveAsync(ApplicationDbContext context, params T[] items)
UpdateAsync(ApplicationDbContext context, params T[] items)
```

I have used above methods for any operation with only one table.

I face problem when I want to access multiple tables.
For that I have to create object for every table that I want to access so that is not good as well.

like this:

```
 using (var context = ApplicationDbContext.Create())
                {
                    try
                    {
                      var repository = new DataRepository<TableClassName>();
                      var skills = await repository.GetAllAsync(context);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                       throw ex;
                    }
                }
```

So is there any solution to use DataRepoitory as an EntitryFramework and access all the tables with one object?

And if not what is preferable direct access Entity Framework in controller or Repository with Asp.Net Web Api?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using your DataRepository only for the operations that it provides now, which are simple. It is unlikely or even impossible that you find a way to abstract all possible queries needed in your application in the DataRepository.
So, as you have a reference to the EF DbContext, implement the more complex queries directly with LINQ or a method chain. You can find many examples of how to query multiple tables and other complex queries with EF.

Comment: Ok but is it possible to do queries using DataRepository or that is mandatory to use EF for queries or multiple table access?

Comment: Do you own the code for this DataRepository? I personally don't see the value in it, but if you can change it, you could add an extra method with the query that you want. My preferred approach would be to create a specific repository or service for each feature (i.e. CustomersService) and in there do the operations you need directly with EF. Don't access EF from your controller.

Comment: Ohhh ok you mean to say I have to create repository for every class that I want to access and than I can do further operrations right?

Comment: Yes. This is much cleaner and gives you freedom to implement queries as complex as you want without polluting your controllers. Also, you can reuse your existing repository methods for the simple operations.